# Persist data in text field after form validation fails - Active Admin

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have a text field that I pre populate with some text, but I am finding if the form validation fails then any extra text I have added is not persisted

```
f.input :description, as: :text, input_html: { rows: 10, cols: 10, value: bike_description }

def bike_description
  "text here"
end
```

So if i added to the text field and it read `text here and some more text`, upon form validation failure the filed would just read `text here`

How could i get this to remember any extra text I added, or would i load the default text in another way ?

I have tried putting this method in my model

```
def bike_description
  read_attribute(:description).presence || 'text here'
end
```

But i get

```
undefined local variable or method `bike_description' for #<ActiveAdmin::Views::ActiveAdminForm:0x007fe9cb2d13a8>
```

Thanks

Comment: You have hardcorded `value: bike_description`, thus it will always return `text here`. What is your intention using that `bike_description` method?

Comment: The purpose of that method is to have a set of default text that can be added to as per the users requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you use the return value of the `bike_description` method as the value for the form field. No matter how description is set on the model, `bike_description` will be shown.

Assuming your database has a `description`, than you can add a default text to the attribute reader by adding a method like this to your model:

```
# remove the overwritten value getter from the form
f.input :description, as: :text, input_html: { rows: 10, cols: 10 }

# add this to your model
def description
  read_attribute(:description).presence || 'text here'
end
```

This will return the current value of the `description` attribute or the default text if the `description` text is blank.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have tried this but any new text that I add is not persisted upon validation failure

Comment: Yes, when you add this to the model, it should be available everywhere in the app. In a view helper you will need something different to call that `read_attribute` method on the actual resource that is currently displayed.

Comment: ok so i have added the method to my model, but get `undefined local variable or method 'bike_description' for #<ActiveAdmin::Views::ActiveAdminForm:0x007fe9cb2d13a8>`
`